# Trying to add a JLabel, but it is stuck in the middle of Jframe

Tags: java, jlabel

I am trying to add a JLabel but the problem is that it is eith stuck in the middle or to the left of the jframe.

Here is my code;

```
public class test extends JFrame{

    public test(){
        JLabel text = new JLabel("test")
        text.setLocation(100,100);
        setTitle("Help me");
        setSize(500,500);
        add(text);

    }
}

public class Runner{
    public static void main (String[] args){
         test a = new test();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you must use absolute positioning, you need to set a null layout and bounds like Cyrille said, but I do agree that probably 99% of the time, your stock layout managers and a little creativity in some cases will do what you want. this link is a little old, but check it out for information about layout managers and stacking them to get desired effects. http://deptinfo.unice.fr/~buffa/java/iup2/2000/gui/AWTLayoutMgr/shortcourse.html

Answer (score 1):

Every container has a layout manager that set the position and size of the elements it contains according to its own rules. `JFrame` default layout is `BorderLayout`, which put things by default on the left.

To position components absolutely, you have to set the layout manager to `null` and explicitely call `repaint()` on your `JFrame` every time you add/remove/modify your components. You also have to set the size of the components, not only their position (use for example `setBounds` to set them all in one call.

As an example, The following code does what you want:

```
public class Test extends JFrame {
    public Test() {

            // remove any layout manager.
        setLayout(null);

        setTitle("Help me");
        setSize(500, 500);

        JLabel text = new JLabel("test");
            // set size and position of component.
        text.setBounds(new Rectangle(100, 100, 200, 200));
            // add component.
        add(text);

            // explicitely call repaint().
        repaint();

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

For more informations, you can look at the [Oracle tutorial on working without a layout manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html).

**Edit**: I would still advise you to use normal layout managers to achieve what you want, as positioning everything absolutely is usually a pain.

Answer (score 0):

```
add(text);
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setVisible(true);
```